# How can I speed up the process of requests about cheaters?

Tags: ingress

You know there is a lot of spoofers, cheaters who have multi accounts and share accounts. I am always submiting requests but it looks like it isn't enough anymore.

- What can I do to speed up the process?
- Is spamming requests with our community OK?
- What is the best effective way to get a quick response?

Answer (score 4):

We generally wouldn't be able to respond, as we are neither Niantic nor know their protocol when it comes to that. But here are few things to consider when it comes to large player base, how it's handled and Ingress

1. The game is pretty old by now and is much less popular than it used to be, meaning it brings in less money than Pokemon, so the team behind the studio would devote more time and resources towards the newer more profitable game.
2. Only one report would rarely be looked at, given the following: man reports towards only one player have much higher chance of being acted on, as obviously there's something wrong with the player and he's being reported much more often - showing up as a much higher risk than a single report player.

The above system is often in place to filter between an actual cheater and a player being reported out of spite for no actual reason.

Answer (score 2):

All what you can do is to make screenshots as proof, create the ticket, and post it in the ingress G+ group with the whole story and pictures. Tag your post with: +Niantic Project ., +John Hanke, +Ingress, +NIA Ops.

Ps: at least NIA makes move on a blue spoofer now at this Shard anomaly what is going on now. A blue player with a green account spoofed to a portal, what has a link to a green target portal, and that spoofer made a longer link to the opposite direction. NIA create a link back so the shard went to the target later. At least they did something.